# Why function that refers to a global function in the same section can only be solved at link time while local functions will be solve at compile time?

Tags: assembly, linker, elf, i386, relocation

I have this assembly file prog.S :

```
    .text
#------------------------------main----------------------------------
    .globl main
    .type main,@function
main:
pushl %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
call myGlobalFunction   # call to my global func
call myLocalFunction    # call to my local func 
popl %ebp
ret
.Lmain_end:
    .size main, .Lmain_end-main
#-------------------------myGlobalFunction---------------------------
    .globl myGlobalFunction
    .type myGlobalFunction,@function
myGlobalFunction:
pushl %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
movl $1, %eax           # return 1
popl %ebp
ret
.LmyGlobalFunction_end:
    .size myGlobalFunction, .LmyGlobalFunction_end-myGlobalFunction
#-------------------------myLocalFunction---------------------------
    .type myLocalFunction,@function
myLocalFunction:
pushl %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
movl $2, %eax           #return 2
popl %ebp
ret
.LmyLocalFunction:
    .size myLocalFunction, .LmyLocalFunction-myLocalFunction
```

With the three functions being in the same .text section, and main that call the global function and then the local one.

When I compile this file with clang :

```
clang.exe -target i386-none prog.S -o prog.o -c
```

Here is the sections I got :

```
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 0000a0 000041 00      0   0  1
  [ 2] .text             PROGBITS        00000000 000034 000023 00  AX  0   0  4
  [ 3] .rel.text         REL             00000000 000098 000008 08   I  4   2  4
  [ 4] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 000058 000040 10      1   2  4
```

the relocation section '.rel.text' :

```
Relocation section '.rel.text' at offset 0x98 contains 1 entry:
 Offset     Info    Type            Sym.Value  Sym. Name
00000004  00000302 R_386_PC32        0000000f   myGlobalFunction
```

the symbol table :

```
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 4 entries:
   Num:    Value  Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND
     1: 00000019    10 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT    2 myLocalFunction
     2: 00000000    15 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    2 main
     3: 0000000f    10 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    2 myGlobalFunction
```

and the .text section disassembly code

```
00000000 <main>:
   0:   55                      push   %ebp
   1:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
   3:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   4 <main+0x4>
   8:   e8 0c 00 00 00          call   19 <myLocalFunction>
   d:   5d                      pop    %ebp
   e:   c3                      ret

0000000f <myGlobalFunction>:
   f:   55                      push   %ebp
  10:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
  12:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
  17:   5d                      pop    %ebp
  18:   c3                      ret

00000019 <myLocalFunction>:
  19:   55                      push   %ebp
  1a:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
  1c:   b8 02 00 00 00          mov    $0x2,%eax
  21:   5d                      pop    %ebp
  22:   c3                      ret
```

I can see from the disassembly code that the PC relative call has already been solved for the local function but the global function is yet to be solve at the linking process..

What I don't understand is **why the assembler cannot solve the global function call which is in the same section that the main function** (and therefore, from what I understood, will always be at the same relative location from main since they are in the same section).

Obviously, if 'main' and 'myGlobalFunction' wouldn't have been in the same section, the assembler could not solve the PC relative call since the linker can put the different section 'where it want' (or where we want by giving a linker script).

*Edit : there is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46112788/why-does-global-symbol-in-the-same-file-needed-to-be-relocated) but there is not a proper answer to it*

Comment: Interestingly, `jmp myGlobalFunction` gets resolved by GAS at assemble time, to a 2-byte `jmp rel8`, but it still uses a relocation on `call myGlobalFunction`.  Unfortunately clang still chooses a relocation for jmp, using a 5-byte `jmp rel32`.  (Tested on x86-64 GNU/Linux with Binutils 2.36.1 and 12.0.1, with `-c -m32` targeting ELF object files like your test, although since I removed the push/pop noise, the -m32 is actually not needed.  Same result with 64-bit builds).  Also on https://godbolt.org/z/szPev9rKx. Even putting main at the bottom so the symbol's already seen doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assembler **can** solve jumping/calling `myGlobalFunction` defined in the same section at asm-time, and sometimes it does so, as [Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes) investigated.
However, as the function is declared *global*, it is assumed to be available from other sections, too.

Assembler thinks that your `.text` section from the file `prog.o` might be statically linkable to other programs at link-time. You are right that in such case `other.o` declares `myGlobalFunction` as *external*, the relocation record should be generated into `other.o`, and relocation of `call myGlobalFunction` in `prog.o` is superabundant. Perhaps clang.exe assumes that the symbol `myGlobalFunction` is potentially *weak* and that it could be replaced at link-time with homonymous global symbol defined in `someother.o`, also linked together with `other.o` and `prog.o`.

Call of a global function in the same section could be resolved at compile time. My guess is that Clang defers this to link-time and generates RIP-relative relocation to enable future replacement of the target function from other module.

Comment: But what I don't get then is why other programs that statically link with prog.o need that reloc entry. The reloc entry basically saying to put the relative location from the end of the call instruction (0x8) to the start of `myGlobalFunction` at 0xf. That will always be the same (0xf-0x8=0x7) since they are in the same section and all that .text section will be taken by other programs that statically link against it (and so will find the exact same relative location). All the other programs would need is the symbol table to know at which offset `myGlobalFunction` and `main` is in the section.

Comment: It might be the other way round: the other program links `prog.o` and it wants to call `myGlobalFunction`. The `.text` section from `prog.o` will be appended to `.text` section of the other program, so the distance between the `call` and `myGlobalFunction`  must be recalculated by the linker.

Comment: Indeed, it will need to be calculated by the linker for the `call ` to `myGlobalFunction` in the other program .text section (and therefore only need to use the symbol table that gives the offset of `myGlobalFunction` in the prog.o .text section) but the relative call from main in prog.o .text section would still be the same and so can be relocated at asm-time.. Obviously there is something I don't get but I don't know what :(

Comment: Perhaps clang.exe creates (an unnecessary) relocation record by inertia whenever it sees a reference to global symbol. It might think that `myGlobalFunction` isn't  necessarily the final target at link-time, because another modules (also linked to the other program) may define another global symbol with the same name.

Comment: Your last comment is my only guess; not exactly symbol interposition (that's a run-time dynamic linking concept), but possible multiple identical definitions?  You should edit your answer to say that; your current answer seems to be missing the point of the question, and is talking about why there's a symbol table entry for `myGlobalFunction`, not why `call myGlobalFunction` has a `R_386_PC32` relocation for the target.

Comment: I think it's more likely that it's just a missed optimization for this case. The assembler does need to support duplicate symbols to implement C++ `inline` keyword linkage semantics, but this symbol isn't declared weak.  But perhaps the assembler's logic for getting these cases right is conservative and uses relocations in some cases where they can't be needed but also aren't harmful.